# When triggering click event for children getting Undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, click

I am trying simulate click for all child nodes in conversation list.
  when i am executing this line of code 
`document.querySelectorAll('[aria-label="Conversations list"]')[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].children[0].children[0].children[1]` getting  this result

```
     <div role="button" tabindex="-1" id="rx-vlv-1" aria-label="grop, group 
         chat, 3, 13:37, No new messages, " style="position: relative; display: flex; flex-direction: column; flex-grow: 0; 
    flex-shrink: 0; overflow: visible; align-items: stretch;
     cursor: pointer; height: 59px; transition: transform 0.4s ease 0s;"> 
     </div>
```

but when i try to preform click getting undefined. i am new to this technology help me if i am wrong

`document.querySelectorAll('[aria-label="Conversations list"]')[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].children[0].children[0].children[1].click();`

Any suggestions ??

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: HTML DOM method `.click()` has no return value

Comment: ok but click is not happening

Comment: it would mean that the element has no `click` event listener

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski how can i click that button . in webpage i am able to click

Comment: You should provide more code. As far as it looks like the button does not trigger any event, so either you are clicking the wrong element or there are some other errors resulting from a piece of code that is missing

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski this  is skype webpage where i am trying to perform click event for conversation list.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the click is performed, but [that function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_click.asp) always returns `undefined`